# Android Studio Reports "Never Used" for HILT Modules, But the App Works Fine

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am managing dependency injection using HILT in my application. I am encountering an issue related to HILT and I need your assistance on this matter.

The issue can be summarized as follows:

While using HILT, I create modules for interfaces. I add these modules to components to manage dependency injection. However, Android Studio marks these modules as "never used" and I receive warnings during code analysis.

The application seems to work correctly. When I delete the modules marked as never used, the application starts to crash.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKKI7.png)

[Ide warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znQmB.png)

My questions are:

- Is this behavior normal?
- What can I do to prevent the modules from being marked as "never used"?
- Is there a possibility that this situation might lead to problems in the future?
- Is there someone experienced in this matter who understands this behavior?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

The application seems to work correctly. When I delete the modules marked as never used, the application starts to crash.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can select your `RemoteDataSourceModule`, press Alt-Enter, then select "Suppress unused warning if annotated by `@Module`"

I'm not sure if there's a Hilt/Dagger plugin for Android Studio, but if you install that it'll probably make the warning go away as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have plugins. I appreciate the suggestion regarding suppressing the unused warning using the @Module annotation. However, I'm still looking for a solution that addresses the underlying issue more directly. While these suggestions are helpful for managing the warnings, I want to ensure that I fully understand and resolve the root cause of the situation.

Comment: @mustafa What about it is still unclear to you? The modules are used, but Android Studio can't know that. So you have to tell it, somehow.